# prevent sql injection attack in dynamic query grails

Tags: sql, grails, sql-injection

I have query as:

```
def selectQuery="select ins"
        def fromQuery = " from InstitutionStudent ins"
        def whereQuery = " where ins.institution=:inst"
        def compareQuery = [inst:inst]
```

and other query as:

```
if(params.pAddress!=""){
   whereQuery += " and ins.address='" + address + "'"

   def check=InstitutionStudent.executeQuery
   ("SELECT ins FROM InstitutionStudent ins 
     WHERE ins.institution=:inst and ins.address='"+address+"'"
    ,[inst:inst])
 }
```

which results for advance search query as

```
def allQuery = selectQuery+fromQuery+whereQuery       
def finalQuery = InstitutionStudent.executeQuery
             (allQuery.toString(),compareQuery)
```

but there is possibility of injection attack so to prevent it how to pass parameterized query to this query?

Comment: If you use query params such as `:param` or `?` instead of string concatenation your app will be immune to SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use usual named parameters:

```
if(params.pAddress!=""){
   whereQuery += " and ins.address= :address"
   compareQuery.address = address
   def check=InstitutionStudent.executeQuery
   ("SELECT ins FROM InstitutionStudent ins 
     WHERE ins.institution=:inst and ins.address=:address"
    ,[inst:inst, address:address])
 }
```